# How do I disable the volatile storage class using command-line options to the compiler?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Is there any way to disable the volatile storage class using only compiler settings/flags  while compiling in gcc *without modifying the underlying source code*?

Ex.

```
volatile int x;
.. use x ..
```

Needs to be compiled as if it were written:

```
int x;
.. use x ..
```

Comment: `#define volatile ` is an ugly hack but could work.

Comment: @Pubby, Any way without code modification?

Comment: @Whoami You mean a flag `-fbugger-the-standard-and-ignore-volatile`?

Comment: @Whoami surely you're able to read the documentation as well as anyone else, and it takes less time than waiting for an answer.

Comment: Instead of `#define volatile` you could pass `-Dvolatile` to the compiler to not modify the code :)

Comment: Why did this receive a down-vote?

Comment: Because, perhaps, someone thought it was a bad idea?

Comment: Why do you think you need to remove `volatile`?  What will be the advantage?  There are contexts (related to signals, and to `setjmp()`) where `volatile` is important, and GCC may start to warn about places where `volatile` should be used.  Technically, you are in violation of the standard if you include a standard header when there is a `#define` for a keyword in place, but using `-Dvolatile=` on the command line is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Compile using

```
gcc -Dvolatile="" ...
```

so that the preprocessor will replace each occurrence of `volatile` with an empty string. If you were to just use `-Dvolatile`, `volatile` would be replaced with 1, which would cause compilation errors.

Because `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the value may change at any point and that it should never cache the value, omitting them from working code will likely cause bugs to appear (as the compiler will sometimes work on stale values).